# Javascript concatenate argument variable

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I am attempting to add a variable to an argument and having no luck with it. Can someone help with this?

As you see, movePage function takes two arguments. The second argument is a variable but I'm having trouble with the proper quotes. I've tried a bunch of ways using single and double quotes with no success.

i.e. var country = "Canada"; (this will not be static)

```
$(".ap_a").first().prop("onClick","movePage(3,".country.")");
```

Comment: I think you're confusing JavaScript with PHP for string concatenation...

Comment: Ahhh! You are right. I need the plus sign. It's been many months since I touched this project. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn’t build code from strings anyway (see: why `eval` is bad) – do `$(".ap_a").first().click(function () { movePage(3, country); });`

Comment: Was the below answer helpful to you? If so, please consider selecting it as the "best answer", or write your own answer and select that as the Best Answer. Doing so is helpful to the StackOverflow community.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
$(".ap_a").first().prop("onClick",`movePage(3,${country})`);
```

or perhaps

```
const hmm = `movePage(3, ${country})`;
$(".ap_a").first().prop("onClick", hmm);
```

Just a guess